# How to determine the difference in days in a list of dates?

Tags: python, pandas, list, datetime

I have a dataframe containing a column which contains a list of dates. The length of dates can range (2+ dates). I was hoping to create a new column that contains the number of days between the minimum and maximum of dates in this list and am not entirely sure the best way to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
data = [
    ["Item_1", ["2020-06-01", "2020-06-02", "2020-07-05"]],
    ["Item_2", ["2018-04-15", "2018-04-22"]],
    ["Item_3", ["2016-02-15", "2016-02-22", "2016-03-05", "2016-04-01"]],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Item_ID", "Dates"])
df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) the `Dates` column, convert [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html#) to find the min and max dates per group, take the [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) of each group, and assign the result back to a new column:

```
df['Duration'] = (
    # explode lists into usable Series and convert to Datetime
    pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'].explode())
        .groupby(level=0).agg(['min', 'max'])  # Get min and max per group
        .diff(axis=1)  # Diff across rows
        .iloc[:, -1]  # Get the resulting difference
)
```

If the lists are guaranteed to be sorted, we can simply subtract the last value in the list from the first to get the duration after converting `to_datetime`:

```
df['Duration'] = (
    # get last value in list and subtract from first value 
    # after converting each to datetime
    pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'].str[-1]) - pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'].str[0])
)
```

Both options produce `df`:

```
  Item_ID                                             Dates Duration
0  Item_1              [2020-06-01, 2020-06-02, 2020-07-05]  34 days
1  Item_2                          [2018-04-15, 2018-04-22]   7 days
2  Item_3  [2016-02-15, 2016-02-22, 2016-03-05, 2016-04-01]  46 days
```

Comment: @user, see my added answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways

Option 1: Keep it numpy and one liner

```
df['Lapse'] =df.agg(lambda x: np.ptp(np.array(x['Dates'], dtype='datetime64')), axis=1)
```

Option 2: Go the long way

1. Explode
2. Coerce date to date time
3. Find differences of the extremes using np.ptpt

   ```
   df=df.explode('Dates')
        df['Dates']=pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'], format='%d,%m,%Y')
        df.groupby('Item_ID').agg(lapse= ('Dates', np.ptp), Dates=('Dates', list))
   ```